# gurobipy.GurobiError: Invalid argument to LinExpr multiplication

Tags: python, syntax-error, gurobi, objective-function

I'm getting the error: `gurobipy.GurobiError: Invalid argument to LinExpr multiplication`
The bug has to be in the following line:

```
m.setObjective(quicksum(sum(s[d, r] *x[d, r] for r in piecewise)
               * h[d] * Z * VarDemand[d] for d in demandStage)
               + quicksum(sum(s[j, r] * x[j, r] for r in piecewise)
               *h[j] * Z * Var[j] for j in intermediateStage),
               GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

`x` is the variable and all the rest are dicts with imported values out of excel files.

I've been staring at this for quite some time, but I can't see the bug.

Comment: You should format this in a manner that we could read, what I can see is that you at least lack an operator after the first sum `...sum(s[d,r]x[d,r] for r in piecewise) h[d]...`

Comment: When I had the error, it was a mismatch of the type of the factors in the sum (I multiplied a Gurobi variable with a list instead of an int). So check the type of your dictonary values and see if the multiplication makes sense.
If you brake the multiplication into multiple lines, you might get more information about which multiplication doesn't work.